# Windows GPO to force a *specific user's* display language?

Tags: windows, language, group-policy

Is it possible to set a specific domain user's Windows 7/8.1/10 language to English, without modifying other user's language preferences, via GPO?

I'm administering computers in overseas offices. The users there like to have Windows in their native language. However, when I RDP or ScreenConnect in as various admin accounts (eg: SamAccountName: `company\it_admin`), I want Windows to be in English.

I've gotten the steps to change the interface language written down for the various Windows versions, but that doesn't help when other IT users log in.

I've found `Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Regional and Language Options\Restricts the UI language Windows users for all logged users` (from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/69a84dc3-3e2a-42c5-ae50-a77ccd499fd5/change-windows-language-by-group-policy?forum=w7itproui)), but the description makes it sounds like it will override the language for all users.

---

P.S.: Mod, if this is better suited in ServerFault, please let me know.

Comment: You can change the language pack, keyboard layout, and interface language all through a PowerShell.  You can also run a PowerShell script, as a group policy, on specific user groups.  I am not aware of any method to force any of those settings for a specific user, outside of not being able to change those settings obviously, I suggest the script method.